# How to load Vue library once and use in any component

Tags: javascript, import, vuejs2, components, shared-libraries

I'm trying to utilize a third party library in Vue CLI (specifically this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto). According to the documentation, I can require the library in my individual components like this:

```
var VueScrollTo = require('vue-scrollto')
```

But what I would rather do is import the library once in my `main.js` file, then reference it from the Vue object. From my experience with other libraries, I would expect it to work like the following. First in my `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto'

Vue.use(VueScrollTo)

new Vue({
  VueScrollTo
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then, I would expect that I should be able to access the library in any component like this:

```
this.$VueScrollTo.scrollTo('#top', 1000)
```

However, it results in the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined"`. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to code and documention you should use `this.$scrollTo('#top', 1000)`

- https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto#programatically
- https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto/blob/master/vue-scrollto.js#L474

Comment: Oh, it was in the documentation after all! I feel stupid. Thanks!